# Yum fails to find dependencies that seem to be installed already

Tags: centos, yum, dependencies, shared-library

I'm unable to "yum install wireshark-gnome" or wireshark on a Centos 7 box.  running from the SU prompt, I get this error at the end:

> ```
> --> Running transaction check
> ---> Package wireshark.x86_64 0:1.10.14-16.el7 will be installed
> --> Processing Dependency: libsmi.so.2()(64bit) for package: wireshark-1.10.14-16.el7.x86_64
> --> Finished Dependency Resolution
> Error: Package: wireshark-1.10.14-16.el7.x86_64 (base)
>            Requires: libsmi.so.2()(64bit)
>            Available: libsmi-0.4.8-13.el7.x86_64 (base)
>                libsmi.so.2()(64bit)
>  You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
> ** Found 1 pre-existing rpmdb problem(s), 'yum check' output follows:
> libsmi-0.4.8-13.el7.x86_64 has missing requires of libsmi.so.2()(64bit)
> ```

But, trying to find that missing library I get:

> ```
> [root@localhost frank]# yum provides libsmi.so.2
> Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks
> Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
>  * base: mirror.hostduplex.com
>  * epel: mirrors.sonic.net
>  * extras: mirror.keystealth.org
>  * updates: mirror.hostduplex.com
> libsmi-0.4.8-13.el7.i686 : A library to access SMI MIB information
> Repo        : base
> Matched from:
> Provides    : libsmi.so.2
>
>
>
>
> libsmi-0.4.8-13.el7.i686 : A library to access SMI MIB information
> Repo        : @base
> Matched from:
> Provides    : libsmi.so.2
> ```

If i try to install the providing package:

> ```
> [root@localhost frank]# yum install libsmi-0.4.8-13.el7.i686
> Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks
> Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
>  * base: mirror.hostduplex.com
>  * epel: mirrors.sonic.net
>  * extras: mirror.keystealth.org
>  * updates: mirror.hostduplex.com
> Package libsmi-0.4.8-13.el7.i686 already installed and latest version
> Nothing to do
> ```

I also tried installing the 64-bit package:

> ```
> [frank@localhost ~]$ sudo yum install libsmi-0.4.8-13.el7.x86_64
> [sudo] password for frank:  Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks
> Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile  * base:
> mirror.hostduplex.com  * epel: mirrors.sonic.net  * extras:
> mirror.keystealth.org  * updates: mirror.hostduplex.com Package
> libsmi-0.4.8-13.el7.x86_64 already installed and latest version
> Nothing to do
> ```

Though I'm not very experienced, it looks to me like I have the package that contains **libsmi.so.2()**, so what is the problem that I'm having.  I updated my repos and completed yum transactions, but nothing seems to help.
Also I'd like to understand what's going on.  Referring to **libsmi.so.2()** , what does the empty parentheses, ** "()" ** mean in the .so name.  I've read about major, minor, version numbering, but I'm not sure how that fits in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to install 64bit architeture of libsmi.so.2
what you have installed (libsmi-0.4.8-13.el7.i686) looks like libsmi for a 32 bit architecture.

For CentOS7, 
https://centos.pkgs.org/7/centos-x86_64/libsmi-0.4.8-13.el7.x86_64.rpm.html

try

```
yum install libsmi-0.4.8-13.el7.x86_64
```

Comment: Thanks.  I tried that.  but its already installed.  I edited my OP to reflect that.

Comment: Actually I already had libsmi-0.4.8-13.el7.x86_64 installed, as you can see in my edited question.  But it must have been missing the correct file, so I " yum removed" it and the "yum installed" wireshark-gnome and let it install the dependancy.  Solved my problem.  Thanks.